# Find relevant entries in existing data.frame and store these items in a new data.frame

Tags: r

I got a data.frame and want to calculate correlations of user and the ratings of different sport events. In a programming language like Java I would probably use two for loops to create my new data frame or collection. I guess in R there is a more comfortable way to achieve this?

The content of my CSV-file which gets read into a data.frame by using read.csv(myfilename.csv):

```
id;User als userName;Event als EventName;RatingDate;RatingValue;
01;joba;Fußball;2017-05-18 16:10;5;
02;joba;Volleyball;2017-05-18 16:11;4;
03;joba;Nordic-Walking;2017-05-18 16:12;2;
04;joba;Yoga;2017-05-18 16:13;1;
05;joba;Kraftsport;2017-05-18 16:14;3;
06;mamu;Fußball;2017-05-18 16:10;5;
07;mamu;Volleyball;2017-05-18 16:11;3;
08;mamu;Nordic-Walking;2017-05-18 16:12;3;
09;mamu;Yoga;2017-05-18 16:13;2;
10;mamu;Kraftsport;2017-05-18 16:14;3;
11;ermu;Fußball;2017-05-18 16:10;1;
12;ermu;Volleyball;2017-05-18 16:11;2;
13;ermu;Nordic-Walking;2017-05-18 16:12;4;
14;ermu;Yoga;2017-05-18 16:13;4;
15;ermu;Kraftsport;2017-05-18 16:14;1;
```

As you can see there is a userName in column 2 and an eventName in column 3. Moreover in the last column there is a rating value. Now I need to create a correlation between the similarity of the users based on their ratings, i.e.

```
x = c(5,4,2,1,3); # joba
y = c(5,3,3,2,3); # mamu
z = c(1,2,4,4,1); # ermu
# Korrelation joba-mamu
dfxy = data.frame(x,y);
dfxz = data.frame(x,z);
resxy = cor(dfxy, method = "pearson");
resxz = cor(dfxz, method = "pearson");
```

Of course the vectors need to be sorted and related to the same kind of event. I am wondering what is the best way to get the necessary vectors for my correlation calculation out of my unsorted data?

Best regards,
Jochen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyverse`

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
```

Sort by `User` and `Event`

```
df1 <- df %>%
          arrange(User, Event)
```

Split `df` into a list by `User`

```
df2 <- split(df1, df1$User)
```

Use `map_df` to convert `RatingValue` into its own data.frame

```
df3 <- map_df(df2, ~.x$RatingValue)
```

Then `cor` of `df3` will give you the correlation of all groups

```
C <- cor(df3)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. There is only a typo in the last line of code. The correct function is 'cor(df3)'.

Comment: Thanks. Edited for posterity

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [recommenderlab package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=recommenderlab). It contains some basic collaborative filtering algorithms and functions to evaluate them.